# Excel comparison for Text in different coloumns

Tags: excel, excel-2013, vba

I have two excel files with the comments data from a survey. One file has all the comments from all the departments and then the other file has it broken down for different departments.

I have categorized the comments in the master file (the one with all comments) and I want to now find the comment within each department in the other file. Will the following code work?

I found a VB Script on the Microsoft Support website

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/213367

If not is there any other way I can do this other than manually?

Answer (score 0):

=IF(ISERROR(MATCH(A1,$C$1:$C$5,0)),"","MATCH")

This worked. It compared all the values in Coloumn C with Column A and then returned the string "MATCH".